# overlay and combine ffmpeg at once

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Initial situation

- video1, h264 (but the codec isn't actually important I guess), duration 10 
  seconds, non-transparent
- video2, flv, duration 10 seconds, transparency

Using video1 as "starting", "background" clip. then after second 5 i'd like to overlay video2 on it. Resulting in a 15 seconds clip.

let me explain it more graphically

```
video1: 111111111111111111
video2:          222222222222222222
result: 111111111333333333222222222
```

Using the FFmpeg overlay filter like this

```
ffmpeg -i K00187_KOMIKER_NIAVARANI_MICHAEL_01.mp4 -i alpha_vid.flv \
  -filter_complex "overlay" test.mp4
```

Of course this just overlays both videos and stops right after video1 has ended.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for `-itsoffset`

```
ffmpeg -i K00187_KOMIKER_NIAVARANI_MICHAEL_01.mp4 -itsoffset 10 \
  -i alpha_vid.flv -filter_complex overlay test.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks! I've found the parameter before and indeed shifts the second video, but the resulting video is still bound to the length of the original video. Is there no way to merge/overlap/combine them?